# Canvas using Javascript,working on Desktop ,but not working on Mobile Phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

**I have made canvas using javascript which works fine on Desktop but does not works on mobile.** On mobile when I try to draw, it only gets scrolled. Please help me with the code to draw on mobile as well.
P.S : I have taken the mobile code from some website ,but it still does not works.
Please tell and explain the code on how to get it draw on mobile ? Thankyou !

EDIT : IT IS LAGGING ON STACKOVERFLOW WHEN YOU RUN THE SNIPPET . HAVE A LOOK HERE PLEASE : https://codepen.io/dikshatakyar/full/YzVgJWK
**EDIT 2 : ISSUE RESOLVED. THANKYOU.**

```js
const canvas=document.querySelector('#draw');

const ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
// all the drawing for the canvas in ctx
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;

ctx.strokeStyle= '#51c9bb';
ctx.lineJoin='round';
ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.lineWidth=30;

//flag
let isDrawing=false; //don't draw when mouse is just moving mouse w/o doing anything

//where to start a line from and then where to end it
let lastX=0;
let lastY=0;
let hue=0;
let direction=true;

function draw(e){
    if(!isDrawing)
    return; //only run in click and drag
console.log(e);
ctx.strokeStyle= `hsl(${hue},100%,50%)`;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY); //start from
ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX,e.offsetY); //go to
ctx.stroke(); //to actually draw the path on canvas
[lastX,lastY]=[e.offsetX,e.offsetY];
// lastX=e.offsetX;
// lastY=e.offsetY;

hue++;
if(hue>=360){
    hue=0;
}
if(ctx.lineWidth>=80 || ctx.lineWidth<=1){
    direction=!direction;
}
if(direction)
ctx.lineWidth++;
else
ctx.lineWidth--;
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',draw);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',(e)=>{
    isDrawing=true;
    [lastX,lastY]=[e.offsetX,e.offsetY];
});


canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',()=>isDrawing=false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout',()=>isDrawing=false);


//canvas on mobile
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```

```css
*{
            margin: 0;
           
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="draw" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: I can't run the code. It's just lagging

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 yes,it is lagging on stackoverflow,please run it on codepen or just simply click on this link : https://codepen.io/dikshatakyar/full/YzVgJWK

Comment: On mobile you should use touchmove and then targetTouches[0].clientX and clientY as your coordinates.

Comment: @ub_coding yes, I have updated the changes,but it is still not working  ON MOBILE . Have a look here : https://codepen.io/dikshatakyar/full/YzVgJWK

Comment: change your touchmove event handler like so (a bit hackish, a final solution would probably use x and y as the parameter for the draw method) 

{
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.offsetX = e.tagetTouches[0].clientX;
    e.offsetY = e.tagetTouches[0].clientY;
    draw(e)
  }

Comment: https://codepen.io/ub_coding/pen/LYyaMLm?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t do much touch stuff but MDN handles touches using

```
   clientX = e.touches[0].clientX;
   clientY = e.touches[0].clientY;
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/clientX

Something like this works using that

```
const canvas=document.querySelector('#draw');

const ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
// all the drawing for the canvas in ctx
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;

ctx.strokeStyle= '#51c9bb';
ctx.lineJoin='round';
ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.lineWidth=30;

//flag
let isDrawing=false; //don't draw when mouse is just moving mouse w/o doing anything

//where to start a line from and then where to end it
let lastX=0;
let lastY=0;
let hue=0;
let direction=true;

function draw(clientX, clientY){
    if(!isDrawing)
    return; //only run in click and drag

ctx.strokeStyle= `hsl(${hue},100%,50%)`;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY); //start from
ctx.lineTo(clientX,clientY); //go to
ctx.stroke(); //to actually draw the path on canvas
[lastX,lastY]=[clientX,clientY];
// lastX=e.offsetX;
// lastY=e.offsetY;

hue++;
if(hue>=360){
    hue=0;
}
if(ctx.lineWidth>=80 || ctx.lineWidth<=1){
    direction=!direction;
}
if(direction)
ctx.lineWidth++;
else
ctx.lineWidth--;
}

//canvas on mobile
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
   e.preventDefault();
   clientX = e.touches[0].clientX;
   clientY = e.touches[0].clientY; 
   isDrawing=true;
   draw(clientX, clientY)
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDrawing=false;
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clientX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    clientY = e.touches[0].clientY;
    draw(clientX, clientY)
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: hidden;` for `*`

Here's the code:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: it is still not working on mobile by adding touch-action

Comment: @Diksha this one?

Comment: still not working with overflow as hidden.